# How to join two tables and show what is missing via database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to join two tables and check correctness with the third one and show what is missing via users list?
I want output like:

> User 105 not found!

I have:

1. All users list:

```
while($all= mysqli_fetch_array($idall))
{
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($all);
   //print_r($all['id']);
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101
    [id] => 101
    [1] => test101
    [name] => test101
)
Array
(
    [0] => 102
    [id] => 102
    [1] => test102
    [name] => test102
)
Array
(
    [0] => 103
    [id] => 103
    [1] => test103
    [name] => test103
)
Array
(
    [0] => 104
    [id] => 104
    [1] => test104
    [name] => test104
)
Array
(
    [0] => 105
    [id] => 105
    [1] => test105
    [name] => test105
)
```

2. Male:

```
foreach($males as $male)
{
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($male);
   //print_r($male['ids']);
   echo '</pre>';

}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ids] => 103
    [name] => somemanname
)
Array
(
    [ids] => 104
    [name] => somemanname
)
```

3. Female:

```
foreach($females as $female)
{
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($female);
   //print_r($male['ids']);
   echo '</pre>';

}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [ids] => 101
    [name] => somewomanname
)
Array
(
    [ids] => 102
    [name] => somewomanname
```

I tried to figure out something with array_merge and array_diff but I can't get it all together.

Thanks for help!

--- EDIT ---

```
while($all = mysqli_fetch_array($idall))
{
         //echo "<pre>";
         //print_r($all);
         //echo "</pre>";
}
         $people = array_merge($males,$females);
         //echo "<pre>";
         //print_r($people);
         //echo "</pre>";
         $resulty = array_diff($all,$people);
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($resulty);
         echo "</pre>";
         foreach($resulty as $res)
         {
            echo "User ".$res["id"]." not found!"."</br>";
         }
```

> print_r($all);

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 101
    [id] => 101
)
Array
(
    [0] => 102
    [id] => 102
)
Array
(
    [0] => 203
    [id] => 203
)
Array
(
    [0] => 204
    [id] => 204
)
Array
(
    [0] => 205
    [id] => 205
)
```

> print_r($people);

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ids] => 103
            [name] => test103
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ids] => 104
            [name] => test104
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ids] => 101
            [name] => test101
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ids] => 102
            [name] => test102
         )

)
```

Next variables not work and i have empty output.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in php or MySQL? Either way, how are you identifying if a user is male or female?

Comment: I edited my post. I use it in php.

Answer (score 0):

With array_merge you can merge some arrays for example:

```
$people = array_merge($males,$females);
```

And with array_diff you can find diffrence between arrays:

```
$result=array_diff(array_column($all, 'id'),array_column($people, 'id'));
print_r($result);
```

And result is:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 105
   [id] => 105
   [1] => test105
   [name] => test105
)
```

And for your target output you can use:

```
foreach($result as $res)
{
   echo "User ".$res["id"]." not found!"."</br>";
}
```

Comment: I edited my post. That code not work for me

Comment: I edit it too;I think it be correct

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `array_diff`, and **since your indices differ** (`'id' !== 'ids'`) use `array_column` to build your parameters.

Assuming `$all` is an array of arrays, something like:

```php
$all = [];
while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($idall))
{
  $all[] = $line;
}
```

Then you just need to do the following:

```php
foreach (array_diff(array_column($all, 'id'), array_column($males, 'ids'), array_column($females, 'ids')) as $nf_id) {
  // this will execute for every member of $all who's id is not found in $males or $females
  echo "User $nf_id not found!\n";
}
```

[Here is my working PHP sandbox](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/6b0e8)

Refer to the docs:

- [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
- [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)